# maui overwrite visualelement and add property

Tags: maui

I like to create a custom visualelement (StackLayout) "LinkStackLayout" and add a property "IsActiveLink". Depending on the property, I would like to call a method.

```
public class LinkStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public bool IsActiveLink { get; set; } 

    public LinkStackLayout()
    {
        SetDefaultLayout(this);

        if (IsActiveLink is false) return;

        if (this?.Handler is null)
        {
            this.HandlerChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (this.Handler != null)
                {
                    SetFeedback();
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            SetFeedback();
        }
    }
```

I use it like:

```
<custom:LinkStackLayout IsActiveLink="True"> ... </...
```

At the constructor of LinkStackLayout IsActiveLink is allways false.

**How can I use the property to decide whether to call the method?**

Comment: you can't.  The constructor is executed before any properties have been assigned

Comment: I don't see how that has any bearing on my comment.  If the only purpose of the property is to control `SetFeedback`, why doesn't that method just check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not check the property value in the method?

```
private void SetFeedback()
{
    if (!IsActiveLink) return;

    // do stuff
}
```